# Stripe Checkout is missing the required `key` parameter. Where to put variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am getting the following alert after trying to use Stripe Checkout:

Stripe Checkout is missing the required `key` parameter. Please contact the website owner or support@stripe.com.

Under initializers I have:

```
 Stripe.rb

Rails.configuration.stripe = {
:publishable_key => ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
:secret_key      => ENV['SECRET_KEY']
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

In my .env file I have:

```
PUBLISHABLE_KEY= 'with my keys'
SECRET_KEY= 'with my keys'
```

I copy and pasted the controller and views from the tutorial on Stripe's website so nothing is wrong with them. Where should I be putting the key information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, ensure that you have installed the `dotenv-rails` gem.

Add this line to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]
```

Then, make sure to `bundle`:

```
$ bundle install
```

which is equivalent to:

```
$ bundle
```

Also note that your syntax is wrong:

```
PUBLISHABLE_KEY= 'with my keys'
SECRET_KEY= 'with my keys'
```

Try a syntax like this:

```
PUBLISHABLE_KEY='with my keys'
SECRET_KEY='with my keys'
```

Or, more clearly, this:

```
PUBLISHABLE_KEY=pk_test_alsdjflaksjdflaksjdflaksjdfl
SECRET_KEY=sk_test_alsdjflaksjdflaksjdflaksjdfl
```

The quotes are OK, but notice there is no space after the `=`.

Comment: i put 'with my keys' in there instead of the actual hardcoded keys.

Comment: But, you have a space after the `=` sign.

Comment: do i need pk_test_ and sk_test_ before the keys though?

Comment: Yes. Those are your Stripe keys.

Comment: Stripe keys contain sk_test and pk_test within the key itself.

Comment: nvm they are included. In my .env file do i need to say if Rails.env.test?

Comment: I think specifying `test` in your Gemfile is sufficient.

Comment: `gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]`

Comment: I don't have anything in my test.rb or production.rb environment files for Stripe. I created a .env file and put the keys in there. That's okay, right. I've done this for other keys.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure about that. You could also try the other answer I posted.

Comment: will dotenv pick up my already created .env file? Or do I need to delete it and create one again?

Comment: I don't see any reason you should delete it, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Thanks Sealocal dotenv solved the problem. Unless you have this gem installed(or Figaro) the .env file doesn't do anything.

Comment: OK, so it was the line in the `Gemfile` that you were missing?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that your `Stripe.rb` edits have not been loaded.

1. Quit your server with `ctrl + c`
2. `$ spring stop`
   => Spring stopped
3. `$ rails server`

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that ENV['SECRET_KEY'] and ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY'] are not already set to different values for different APIs other than Stripe.  If so, you can change them to ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'] and ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'] to keep them separate.